# MySQL transaction with many updates

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I have a table with 100,000 records. 
I'm considering using a transaction to update the data. 
There will be one query that will update one column to zero and roughtly 5000 updates that each will update one record.

What are the memory implications with these large transactions?
Will be there any significant issues with selecting data while the transaction is running?

---

edit

- table is innodb
- it's 1+5000updates
- and records are updated by column that is indexed

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Have you tried running this on your server? Answers would be pure speculation as we don't know your server specs / architecture nor your MySQL settings.

Comment: One presumes that these 5000 updates are being executed within a loop, in which case the values written on each iteration are determinable programatically?  If so, can that program not be made into an expression that could be placed in a *single* `UPDATE` command?  It sounds as though you're trying to use SQL like a procedural language, when it is in fact a declarative one.

Comment: Yes, these updates are executed inside a loop. Data are determined from XML file. Should I use "case when then end"? In what way will that syntax make it better?

Comment: MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  1 transaction?  2? 1+5000 transactions?  UPDATE by PRIMARY KEY?  Other key?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and sample `UPDATE`s.

Comment: I have updated my original post.

Comment: The transaction should be as long as it is required by the domain model.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  2 `UPDATE` statements -- 1 for the zero, one for the other 5000.  But perhaps that is not practical?

Plan B:  (Not as efficient as Plan A)  5001 `UPDATE` statements in a single transaction (`BEGIN...COMMIT`)

Plan C:  (very slow)  autocommit=1, but no `BEGIN..COMMIT`

None have "memory" problems.  However, it is advisable to have innodb_buffer_pool_size set to about 70% of *available* RAM.

If all the necessary blocks are cached (which might be dozens of blocks or thousands), then Plan A or B will take perhaps a few seconds.  Plan C is likely to take minutes, depending on some innodb settings.

A `SELECT` should not be impacted much by any of the approaches.  There *could* be *some* impact because of the interactions of the row-level locks.  You will *probably* not notice the impact.